# NSIS: makensis crashes with -1073741819 (access violation)

Tags: nsis, access-violation

For apparently no reason NSIS compiler crashes in the middle of nowhere and returns -1073741819 (aka ‭FFFFFFFF C0000005‬ aka access violation) while printing the summary:

```
15:47:40  Install: 1 page (64 bytes), 1 section (16408 bytes), 91 instructions (2548 bytes), 2576 strings (25354 bytes), 17 language tables (3570 bytes).
15:47:40  Uninstall: 4 pages (320 bytes), 1 section (16408 bytes), 469 instructions (13132 bytes),
```

It just stops execution in the middle of the line without any error, not even with verbose logging.

Comment: Try the preview version posted on the NSIS forum.

Comment: works like a charm with the new release, thanks

Answer (score 0):

After going in circles for days I figured out that it actually works with unicode disabled.

Googling with the additional keyword "unicode" finally brought me to this bug:
https://sourceforge.net/p/nsis/patches/300/

Since the bug is about counting strings and the crash happens right before printing the number of total strings it is very likely that the fix expected for 3.07 should fix it.